# MPI_SendRecv deadlock on execution

Tags: mpi

I'm trying to send information from one processor to another in a ring way from an offset processor using MPI_Sendrecv but i got deadlock. What is wrong in my code? Basically i need to use MPI_SendRecv to solve this kind of problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int offset = 9;
    int size, rank, value, next, prev, sendval, recval, namelen;
    double t0, t;
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);

    value = 5;

    if (size > 1)
    {
        next = (rank + 1)% size;
        prev = (size+rank - 1)% size;

        sendval = value + rank;

        if (rank == offset)
        {
            MPI_Sendrecv(&sendval, 1, MPI_INT, next, 1, &recval, 1, MPI_INT, prev, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        }
        else
        {
     
            MPI_Recv(&recval, 1, MPI_INT, prev, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Send(&sendval, 1, MPI_INT, next, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i was using 10.

Comment: No, i want 9 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatched message tags:

```c
MPI_Sendrecv(&sendval, 1, MPI_INT, next, 1, &recval, 1, MPI_INT, prev, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
//                                       ^
...     
MPI_Recv(&recval, 1, MPI_INT, prev, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
//                                  ^^
```

The tag in the send part of the send-receive operation should also be `10`.

Comment: Thank you, didn't notice that moment.